# Repeating ndarray along axis

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

Assume an array of size (in general) `TxNxM`

```
arr = np.array([[[0.83, 0.3 , 0.22],
                 [0.17, 0.33, 0.37]],

                [[0.  , 0.28, 0.09],
                 [0.  , 0.1 , 0.18]],

                [[0.  , 0.  , 0.08],
                 [0.  , 0.  , 0.05]],

                [[0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
                 [0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]]])
```

What I'd like to get is an array of size `TxMxNxN` that looks like this:

```
np.stack((np.repeat(arr[0,:,0:T-1], N, axis = 0).T.reshape(T-1, N, N),
          np.repeat(arr[1,:,0:T-1], N, axis = 0).T.reshape(T-1, N, N),
          np.repeat(arr[2,:,0:T-1], N, axis = 0).T.reshape(T-1, N, N),
          np.repeat(arr[3,:,0:T-1], N, axis = 0).T.reshape(T-1, N, N)))
```

so the output is

```
array([[[[0.83, 0.83],
         [0.17, 0.17]],

        [[0.3 , 0.3 ],
         [0.33, 0.33]],

        [[0.22, 0.22],
         [0.37, 0.37]]],


       [[[0.  , 0.  ],
         [0.  , 0.  ]],

        [[0.28, 0.28],
         [0.1 , 0.1 ]],

        [[0.09, 0.09],
         [0.18, 0.18]]],


       [[[0.  , 0.  ],
         [0.  , 0.  ]],

        [[0.  , 0.  ],
         [0.  , 0.  ]],

        [[0.08, 0.08],
         [0.05, 0.05]]],


       [[[0.  , 0.  ],
         [0.  , 0.  ]],

        [[0.  , 0.  ],
         [0.  , 0.  ]],

        [[0.  , 0.  ],
         [0.  , 0.  ]]]])
```

But this approach doesn't seem to be efficient code-wise and I feel that the same output is achievable using `np.repeat` or `np.tile`. The question is how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [np.broadcast_to](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) and [ndarray.transpose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html#numpy.ndarray.transpose):

```
T, N, M = arr.shape
np.broadcast_to(arr.transpose(0, 2, 1)[..., None], (T, M, N, N))
```

This is considerably faster than using [repeat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng()

shape = 50, 51, 52
T, N, M = shape

arr = rng.random(shape)

assert np.array_equal(np.repeat(arr[..., None], N, axis=3).swapaxes(1, 2), np.broadcast_to(arr.transpose(0, 2, 1)[..., None], (T, M, N, N)))

%timeit np.repeat(arr[..., None], N, axis=3).swapaxes(1, 2)
%timeit np.broadcast_to(arr.transpose(0, 2, 1)[..., None], (T, M, N, N))
```

```
18.6 ms ± 164 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.13 µs ± 5.57 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Comment: The broadcast_to result is readonly.  Depending on how  it's used, it may be sufficient to leave the array (T,M,N,1) shaped.  When used in calculations this will broadcast the same as the (T,M,N,N) shape.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me:

```
N = arr.shape[1]
expected = np.repeat(arr[..., None], N, axis=3).swapaxes(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired output using NumPy's `repeat`, `swapaxes` and `reshape` capabilities

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[[0.83, 0.3 , 0.22],
                 [0.17, 0.33, 0.37]],

                [[0.  , 0.28, 0.09],
                 [0.  , 0.1 , 0.18]],

                [[0.  , 0.  , 0.08],
                 [0.  , 0.  , 0.05]],

                [[0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
                 [0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]]])

T, N, M = arr.shape

result = np.repeat(arr[:, :, 0:T-1, np.newaxis], N, axis=3)
result = result.swapaxes(1, 2)
result = result.reshape(T, M, N, N)

print(result)
```

You can check on my kaggle [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/edgarsitohang/notebookb7e9b62f09/edit)

Comment: code updated and add kaggle link